# how to get async webrequest result and use the result another function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, webrequest

I am trying async webrequest and i want to use return data in another function.

request.js

```js
var fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function postAsync(url)
{
    var response =await fetch(url, 
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent': 'AirPlay/320.20',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        },
        body: {},
        encoding: null
    });

    return await response;
}

module.exports = {
    postAsync
}
```

app.js

```
var request = require('./request');

var response=login();
showData(response.data);

async function login()
{
    var response=await request.postAsync("https://httpbin.org/post");
    return response;
}

function showData(data)
{
    console.log(data);
}
```

run app.js get "undefined" result.
if I change;

```
var response=login();
```

to

```
var response=await login();
```

I get error "await is only valid in async function"

Comment: Change the last line in login(), - include an await  "return await response;"

Comment: I changed but not working. I get "Promise { <pending> }" message

Comment: Yes you need to have any awaits inside an async function. What happens when you run that last piece of code?

Comment: I would like to send the value to the next function in each rotating response.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js doesn't currently allow top-level `await` outside of an async function. Also, it does not look like the `async` function is being executed asynchronously in the scope and context of `app.js`, there is nothing to let the node process know to wait for `login()` to complete.

Try the following

In app.js

```
const request = require('./request');

// Immediately invoke the async function
const login = (async function() {
    const response = await request.postAsync("https://httpbin.org/post");
    // You could just do showData(response.data) here if your goal is just  to log it
    return response;
})();

var response = showData(response.json());

function showData(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Also in your `request.js` file, it doesn't really make sense to `return await response` since you're already `await`ing the declaration of the variable. You may as well just do the following:

I am trying async webrequest and i want to use return data in another function.

request.js

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch')

async function postAsync(url) {
    return await fetch(url, 
        {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'User-Agent': 'AirPlay/320.20',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        },
        body: {},
        encoding: null
    });
}

module.exports = {
    postAsync
}
```

Comment: I tried but not worked. "response.data" not wait to request result and i get error "undefined"

Comment: @gokhansea i made an edit. `response.data` is not apart of the `node-fetch` api. Try `response.json()`